# How can I delete an organisation from IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

In IBM Bluemix you can create and be the member of multiple Organisations. How can I remove redundant organisations?

Answer (score 5):

Deleting an existing organization is not possible at this time. This is limited to Bluemix Public. If you are a Bluemix Dedicated (or) Local user, you can delete existing organizations.

Please see : https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#orgsandspaces

Comment: This is now possible - see Bram's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think org delete must be manually done by bluemix support team. So open a ticket to get it done.

At this doc page
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/adminpublic.html#orgmng

It says:

> Deleting an existing organization
>
> Contact Bluemix registration and ID support to delete your
>   organization.
>
> Note: Deleting operations cannot be reversed. You lose all your
>   applications and services that are associated with the organization.

Comment: Unfortunately after over 3 months of toing and froing with IBM Support, the conclusion was it is not possible;

> 07/06/2016 10:52:50 Client Follow Up [IBM] Emilia Amato Hello Derek,

yes, it seems that the documentation has not been updated with the new behaviour but currently organizations can not be deleted. We will update the doc.

Apologies for any inconvenience.

Thank you.
Best regards,
Emilia
Bluemix Suppor

Answer (score 0):

You are able to delete organizations using the BX plug-in, also on Bluemix Public. Download and install the CF and BX plug-in using the link below
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#cli

Then use these commands below in the command line:

bx login
bx iam org-delete ORG_NAME [-f --all]

Comment: Thank you @Bram , I have run that command - I still see the Orgs in the web console, but will see if that settles after a few days :)

Comment: @DerekMunneke when i reloaded the web interface 5 minutes later the orgs were removed (i might have logged out and back in). Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix evolved over time from a Cloud Foundry public cloud offering over having Local and Dedicated editions to what is IBM Cloud today. There is Cloud Foundry and Cloud Foundry Enterprise Edition (CFEE). CFEE gives users access to the full administrator access and hence more options.

Thus, the answer depends on the context:

- [for CFEE there is a CLI command](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cli_cfee.html#ibmcloud_cfee_org_delete) `ibmcloud cfee org-delete`
- for the regular (old) public Cloud Foundry it is possible to delete spaces and users, but not orgs. This can be done through [the CLI commands](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cli_acct_org_role.html).

There is still a **Bluemix Admin** plugin for Bluemix Local and Bluemix Dedicated (Cloud Foundry for those environments) that allows to delete organizations. However, it does not work on IBM Cloud with Cloud Foundry.